# Setting custom user control's property by inline coding

Tags: c#, asp.net

My user control looks like this :

```
<UC:UCControl ID="ucLogout" runat="server" TestValue="
     <%Server.UrlEncode(Session["upCSRF"].ToString())%>"/>
```

I want to set TestValue property of my user control, but it gives me `Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.` error.

```
public string TestValue { get; set; }
```

How can i solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is obvious, you can not set server components by inline coding.

Why don't you just set that property at your code behind file ?

```
ucLogout.TestValue = Server.UrlEncode(Session["upCSRF"].ToString())
```